# Sum of squares of factors of n correspond to finite groups of order n

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This question is motivated by the fact that if we have a finite group $G$ of order $n$, then the sum of squares of degrees of the irreducible representations of $G$ is equal to $n$. Also, the degrees divide $n$.

In other words, given a group, there is a decomposition of $n$ into a sum of squares of its factors. What I want to know is the following: given a sum of squares of factors of $n,$ where at least one factor is 1, is there a group $G$ of order $n$ whose sum of squares of degrees of irreducible characters is the given sum?

Comment: Irreducible representations of cyclic groups have degree $1$, so just let $n=13=2^2+3^2$, say  Or $n=17=1^2+4^2$ (since you probably meant to require that $1^2$ be one of the summands).

Comment: Yes thank you. I forgot to add that stipulation

Comment: Keeping it simple, $5=1^2+2^2$, but there is only one group of order $5$.

Comment: @david 2 is not a factor of 5

Comment: Ah, I see. You have added that extra condition. Fine. More counterexamples are trivial to make. $15=6\cdot 1^2+3^2$. There is only one group of order $15$.

Comment: More interestingly, it is a wide open question (Brauer's Problem 1) as to which collections of integers are the character degrees of a finite group.